# The argument type 'JsObject'can't be assigned to the type 'buildContext'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a getting this sudden unknown error. On every page that uses context. It appears in codes like

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
```

And

```
Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=> Homepage()));
```

Comment: It might be that you are not passing the *context*  down the widgets or it might be the conflict of an import, but I am not sure since you have not shown your code.

Comment: Have you created a JsObject and named it context?

Comment: It should be with the import because I have many dart files and I had imports in some files starting with 'package:' and some with just the 'filename.dart'  so I changed all the imports on all the dart pages and this happened. What should I do now? Do the imports again?

Comment: Alex Collette, no I haven't